# randomForest predictions contain missing values

Tags: r, random-forest, na, predict

I train a randomForest model with a dataset containing 500 observations and 25 predictors, some of the feature values in mydata are missing.

```
model.train <<- randomForest( RESP ~ .
                              data = mydata,
                              subset = TrainSet, 
                              replace = TRUE,
                              ntree = 1000,
                              na.action = na.roughfix )
```

In the next step, I predict the values for the full dataset with the trained model:

```
predict.full <- predict(model.train, mydata.full, type="response")
```

However, I get missing values for many observation, when some of their features are missing.

Why do I get missing values, shouldn't the setting na.action = na.roughgix prevent it?

Comment: Package `gbm` does not provide a `randomForest` function.

Comment: You are certainly right, it's in the randomForest package..